# Why percentage in price difference changes all the time with the same data?

Tags: reactjs, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm using am4Charts to display a XY chart of price changes as well as a percentage. To display percentage change I use `series.dataItems.last.values.valueY.changePercent` but it always returns different values for the same mock data of only 4 data items. Why is it acting like that? How do I accurately calculate change in price using am4Charts library? Here is the mock data:

```
const data = [
      { date: "2017-12-01", value: "125.5" },
      { date: "2017-12-04", value: "127" },
      { date: "2017-12-05", value: "127.5" },
      { date: "2017-12-06", value: "127.5" }
    ];
```

The rest of simplified code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [thechangeInStock, setthechangeInStock] = useState<number>(0);
  let chart: any;

  const createChart = () => {
    const data = [
      { date: "2017-12-01", value: "125.5" },
      { date: "2017-12-04", value: "127" },
      { date: "2017-12-05", value: "127.5" },
      { date: "2017-12-06", value: "127.5" }
    ];

    chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
    chart.data = data;
    chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";

    const dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
    const valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

    // Create series
    const series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
    series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
    series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
    series.tooltipText = "{value}";
    series.strokeWidth = 3;
    series.minBulletDistance = 25;

    chart.events.on("ready", function () {
      setthechangeInStock(series.dataItems.last.values.valueY.changePercent);
      console.log(series.dataItems.last.values.valueY.changePercent);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    createChart();

    return function cleanup() {
      if (chart) {
        chart.dispose();
      }
    };
  }, []);
  return <div className="App">{thechangeInStock}%</div>;
}
```

Reproducible code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-darkness-nghzr?file=/src/App.tsx:219-1520

Full Gist:

https://gist.github.com/Limpuls/92a73d5807b5289da9eaa690d87091d8

Comment: If I verify the code in the sandbox, I get the same value: `1.593625498007968%` consistently. What value is changing?

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that. It means that the problem is not with the library but with my react code. This is just a small snippet. In my real code there is a bunch of async functions making requests to Firestore to get trading data and it console.log out correct `changePercentage` but the state gets updated with different values all the time. I won't be able to make a reproducible code for that, but perhaps I can share a Gist with full code?

Comment: I think that would be best, but I recommend breaking it down a bit further. As you know now, the problem is not with calculating the `changePercentage` value - so there must be something else.

Comment: @SebastianAmmon After playing with this a bit more I found interesting behaviour. https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-darkness-nghzr?file=/src/App.tsx:568-651 If you uncomment lines 14 and 15 to add themes and reload the page, the percentage value starts acting weird again. It changes on every reload and returns wrong calculations. Do you have any idea why it would act this way because of those two lines of code that seems to have nothing to do with anything apart visual side of things.